# Rails using .map(&:user) and adding HTML tags when looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enumeration

Can you add HTML tags when I have something like this:

```
= skit.challenges.map(&:user).flatten.uniq.compact
```

I'd like to add some `ul` and `li` when it loops through the record. Is this possible or do I have to change this completely?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely possible, although you should avoid putting that kind of logic in the view. In a loop for Rails, just open/close your web tags with the logic and then do the same thing at the end.

```
<ul>
<% @skit_users.each do |user| %>
  <li><%= user.name %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use content_tag helper

```
arr = ["sdf<div>sdf</div>", "<script>alert(123)</script>", "sdf"]

content_tag(:ul, arr.map{|e| content_tag(:li, e) }.inject(:+))

>> "<ul><li>sdf&lt;div&gt;sdf&lt;/div&gt;</li><li>&lt;script&gt;alert(123)&lt;/script&gt;</li><li>sdf</li></ul>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
["a", "b", "c"]
>> a = arr.map {|u| "<ul>#{u}</ul>"}
["<ul>a</ul>", "<ul>b</ul>", "<ul>c</ul>"]

a = arr.map {|u| "<ul>#{u}</ul>"}.flatten.uniq.compact
["<ul>a</ul>", "<ul>b</ul>", "<ul>c</ul>"]
```

You can try something like this, as i understand you want to create some html element on the fly for your view files.

Comment: You should use `content_tag(:ul, u)` instead of `"<ul>#{u}</ul>"` to create a proper `SafeBuffer`.

Comment: i have written with a an assumption, hellomello would like to have this code in controller. If in view, my ans would be similar to Rockster160